# SQL Server banding timepoints based on value

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, lag, lead

I have audit data captured over time points which I would like to aggregate up to display where the value was the same over a period of time using SQL Server 2014.

Taking the below example data

[image]

I would like to transpose it to this ideally without using a cursor - you will see that the output is recording the time period where the value is the same and as such, the same value can be repeated over different periods (seen in rows 3 and 6).

[image]

I have been looking at `LEAD()` and `LAG()` as potential solutions, however I cannot fathom out how to make this work in order to band by time for the same value

Any direction would be gratefully received

Comment: So you're looking for groups of `value` which are the same, but only as they appear in continuous blocks with regard to increasing time?  If so, then this is a gaps and islands problems of sorts.

Comment: You should show sample data which makes this requirement clear.  Your current data leads to a simple `GROUP BY` query, which isn't what you want.

Comment: exactly - you can see that in the output row 3 and 6 have the same value but occurred within a different time banding.  In short, I am trying to convert this discrete data stream into a more contiguous structure to aid querying

Comment: Edited the question to hopefully make the requirement clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case the column [value] doesnt contain distinct number, you can use this query

```
 SELECT start,end,value 
 FROM (SELECT MIN(ts) start
             ,MAX(ts) end
             ,value
             ,C 
       FROM (SELECT ts
                   ,value
                   ,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts) 
                    - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value ORDER BY ts)) C
             FROM YourTable) x
 GROUP BY value,C) y ORDER BY start
```

Comment: Excellent - this is exactly what I was after and works perfectly - thanks

Comment: This is a really great answer, something to keep in mind.  Here is a [link to a demo](http://rextester.com/ZQLAR86014) showing the query in action.  It works.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing your further comments, the below is obviously of no use...

I think you may be over complicating it. If you are looking for the minimum and maximum ts per distinct value, then you can just use MIN & MAX and group by the Value, e.g.

```
SELECT   MIN(ts) AS [Start]  ,
         MAX(ts) AS [End]    , 
         Value
FROM     Table
GROUP BY Value
```